# Emberjs: Change in query-param not reflecting in controller property

Tags: ember.js

I have binded a query-param within controller:

```
Profile.MoviesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['type'],
  type:"horror,action,romantic,biography",
});
```

I am looking for change in query-param in my route:

```
Profile.MoviesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    queryParamsDidChange: function(params) {
      console.log("queryParamsDidChange",params,this.get('controller').get('type'));
    }
  }
});
```

Lastly, in my view I am using links to each of the 'types':

```
{{linkTo "Horror" (query-params type="horror")}}, {{linkTo "Action" (query-params type="action")}} ...
```

The problem is that whenever I click any link - say 'Horror' one - then though `queryParamsDidChange` hook is called and the `params` argument contains `{type:'horror'}`, but the `'type'` property on the controller- `this.get('controller').get('type')` - is still `"horror,action,romantic,biography"`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your controller you're setting the default value of 'type' to the string value of "`horror,action,romantic,biography`" - that won't match anything you want.

Next, `queryParamsDidChange` is called before the value has been set on the type property, example,

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {  
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
  actions: {
    queryParamsDidChange: function(params) {
       console.log("queryParamsDidChange : was " + this.get('controller.type')); 
       console.log("queryParamsDidChange : will be " + (params.type || 'default value'));
    }
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['type'],
  type: "horror"  // the default value, won't appear in URL or params
})
```

A jsbin with this working example is http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jeqijoguku/1/

Comment: `// the default value, won't appear in URL or params` How would you make it show in query params?